# ABAC for NoSQL databases

Tags: database, authorization, access-control, abac

If I need to access to a database using ABAC model I know there are some possibilities (for example if the database is Oracle, one could use Oracle VPD).
Nevertheless, all the solutions I found are only for relational databases. Is it possible to implement ABAC with NoSQL databases?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Axiomatics, where I work, provides an ABAC solution that can be used for a wide range of systems. There is one dedicated solution that applies ABAC to relational databases but beyond that there is a generic API-based solution you can use to secure a wider range of systems.

When you want to implement ABAC with a NoSQL system (or any system that contains a vast amount of data), you have 2 options:

- provision authorization configuration to the target system. In that case you leverage the target's ability to define authorization. It's an approach taken by provisioning and governance systems (e.g. Sailpoint) but also Axiomatics via its Policy Server and its Reverse Query API
- generate filter expressions that are applied at runtime before the query goes to the NoSQL system. This is the same approach Oracle VDP or ADAF MD take on relational databases. In that case, there is a notion of a Policy Enforcement Point (PEP - part of the standard ABAC architecture). Again, Axiomatics provides you with the SDKs so you can integrate yourself with your own systems and generate the filters you are interested in (be it NoSQL or something else).

Depending on the system you are dealing with, this may be a task that is easy or arduous. Doing filtering for LDAP is child's play but doing it for SQL is much harder (which is why we provide SQL OOTB).

I hope this helps,

David.